# how to achive smooth page navigation in silverlight window phone sdk. as shown in picture below

Tags: jquery, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to achieve smooth page navigation like jquery slider in window phone 8 using silver-light controls or any other control how to do this, below is demo of that smooth navigation show page in bullets representation.

[image: screenshot of image]

Comment: what about a panorama page ! ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Windows phone Panorama control for similar navigation, In windows phone you can list this impendent page as panorama items. You cans use this [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941109%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to learn more about Panorama control. Alternatively you can use Pivot Control too.

Here is the link for sample application [Sample App](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/PanoramaPivot-Sample-332a7e06)

Comment: well thanks for your answer, but if i have more then three pages then how it can be possible in panorama view...

Comment: You can make use of Pivot control. I created 4-5 page panorama control in my application. It will work without any issue. Suppose if you have more pages, use pivot control, instead of Panorama